# How to get the format category (datatype) of a text field in a pdf with pdftk?

Tags: php, pdf, formatting, pdftk

I have a Linux web server and am creating a php application that works with pdf files. Current I am using pdftk to read all the field names and field types of pdf's that are uploaded to my server.

Everything is working great but the issue I am having now is I cannot tell what the format category (also know as the datatype) is for the text fields. If it is set to "None" then it works like a normal text field I can assign any text to it and wont have any issues. But once someone selects a different value I am having issues.

For example a text field with a format category of "Number" will only allow numbers to be assigned to it. If I attempt to send text to it the field just wont display it. Same issue goes with the format category's of "Percentage", "Date", "Time", "Special", and "Custom". There has to be some way to determine what it is so I can let the user know exactly what type of data they can enter into the field.

Answer (score 2):

Fields are validated and/or formatted according to their `AA` (additional actions) entry, which practically is JavaScript function call. Unfortunately, `pdftk` ignores this entry and doesn't export it neither to FDF (`generate_fdf`) nor text (`dump_data_fields`). Messing with `pdftk`'s source is above my abilities. If you won't find any ready-made solution that extracts this kind of information from PDF form, you can write a small program using API that either provides access to all field's properties or low level COS structure. E.g.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -MCAM::PDF -we '
my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($ARGV[0]) or die();
for ($doc->getFormFieldList()) {
    my $field = $doc->getFormField($_);
    next unless defined $field;
    my $dict = $doc->getValue($field);
    next unless exists $$dict{FT} and 
        $doc->getValue($$dict{FT}) eq "Tx";
    print "Field \"$_\" ";
    my $AA = $doc->getValue($$dict{AA});
    my $F = $doc->getValue($$AA{F});
    my $JS = $doc->getValue($$F{JS});
    print $JS ? "is formatted as \"$JS\"\n" : "is a plain text\n";
}
' MIVoterRegistration_97046_7.pdf
```

Sorry for example PDF :-), that's the first quick google result that, I checked, *does* contain `AA`s. And output is

```
Field "LastName" is a plain text
Field "FirstName" is a plain text
Field "Middle Name" is a plain text
Field "Address" is a plain text
Field "Apart#" is a plain text
Field "City" is a plain text
Field "ZipCode" is a plain text
Field "Telephone" is formatted as "AFSpecial_Format(2);"
Field "describe" is a plain text
Field "c/t" is a plain text
Field "County" is a plain text
Field "School" is a plain text
Field "MailAddress" is a plain text
Field "DOB" is a plain text
Field "DLNumber" is a plain text
Field "DLState" is a plain text
Field "SSNumber" is a plain text
Field "PrevAddress" is a plain text
Field "PrevC/T" is a plain text
Field "PrevCounty" is a plain text
Field "PrevState" is a plain text
Field "PrevZipCode" is a plain text
Field "PrevName" is a plain text
```

Functions, that define field format, are described [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/FormsAPIReference.pdf), and `AFSpecial_Format(2)` is indeed phone number format. Curiously, it looks like all other form's fields were thought unimportant by form's creators :-).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll check it out and let you let you know if I am able to get everything to work.